# I got this really long Java code and I don't know how to shorten it

Tags: java

So I have this really long Java code that takes up 2000 lines and it's like just the same code that I have to repeat a lot of times. Is there any way to write this shorter?

```
for(int d=0;d<6;d++) {
            for(int c=0;c<2;c++) {
                if(players[d][c].contains ("SA")) {
                    if(d==0){
                        if(c==0) {
                            p1a.setIcon(SA);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p1b.setIcon(SA);
                        }
                    } else if(d==1) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p2a.setIcon(SA);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p2b.setIcon(SA);
                        }
                    } else if(d==2) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p3a.setIcon(SA);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p3b.setIcon(SA);
                        }
                    } else if(d==3) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p4a.setIcon(SA);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p4b.setIcon(SA);
                        }
                    } else if(d==4) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p5a.setIcon(SA);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p5b.setIcon(SA);
                        }
                    } else if(d==5) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p6a.setIcon(SA);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p6b.setIcon(SA);
                        }
                    }
                } else if(players[d][c].contains ("S2")) {
                    if(d==0){
                        if(c==0) {
                            p1a.setIcon(S2);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p1b.setIcon(S2);
                        }
                    } else if(d==1) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p2a.setIcon(S2);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p2b.setIcon(S2);
                        }
                    } else if(d==2) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p3a.setIcon(S2);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p3b.setIcon(S2);
                        }
                    } else if(d==3) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p4a.setIcon(S2);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p4b.setIcon(S2);
                        }
                    } else if(d==4) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p5a.setIcon(S2);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p5b.setIcon(S2);
                        }
                    } else if(d==5) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p6a.setIcon(S2);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p6b.setIcon(S2);
                        }
                    }
                } else if(players[d][c].contains ("S3")) {
                    if(d==0){
                        if(c==0) {
                            p1a.setIcon(S3);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p1b.setIcon(S3);
                        }
                    } else if(d==1) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p2a.setIcon(S3);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p2b.setIcon(S3);
                        }
                    } else if(d==2) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p3a.setIcon(S3);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p3b.setIcon(S3);
                        }
                    } else if(d==3) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p4a.setIcon(S3);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p4b.setIcon(S3);
                        }
                    } else if(d==4) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p5a.setIcon(S3);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p5b.setIcon(S3);
                        }
                    } else if(d==5) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p6a.setIcon(S3);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p6b.setIcon(S3);
                        }
                    }
                } else if(players[d][c].contains ("S4")) {
                    if(d==0){
                        if(c==0) {
                            p1a.setIcon(S4);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p1b.setIcon(S4);
                        }
                    } else if(d==1) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p2a.setIcon(S4);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p2b.setIcon(S4);
                        }
                    } else if(d==2) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p3a.setIcon(S4);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p3b.setIcon(S4);
                        }
                    } else if(d==3) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p4a.setIcon(S4);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p4b.setIcon(S4);
                        }
                    } else if(d==4) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p5a.setIcon(S4);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p5b.setIcon(S4);
                        }
                    } else if(d==5) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p6a.setIcon(S4);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p6b.setIcon(S4);
                        }
                    }
                } else if(players[d][c].contains ("S5")) {
                    if(d==0){
                        if(c==0) {
                            p1a.setIcon(S5);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p1b.setIcon(S5);
                        }
                    } else if(d==1) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p2a.setIcon(S5);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p2b.setIcon(S5);
                        }
                    } else if(d==2) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p3a.setIcon(S5);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p3b.setIcon(S5);
                        }
                    } else if(d==3) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p4a.setIcon(S5);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p4b.setIcon(S5);
                        }
                    } else if(d==4) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p5a.setIcon(S5);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p5b.setIcon(S5);
                        }
                    } else if(d==5) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p6a.setIcon(S5);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p6b.setIcon(S5);
                        }
                    }
                } else if(players[d][c].contains ("S6")) {
                    if(d==0){
                        if(c==0) {
                            p1a.setIcon(S6);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p1b.setIcon(S6);
                        }
                    } else if(d==1) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p2a.setIcon(S6);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p2b.setIcon(S6);
                        }
                    } else if(d==2) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p3a.setIcon(S6);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p3b.setIcon(S6);
                        }
                    } else if(d==3) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p4a.setIcon(S6);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p4b.setIcon(S6);
                        }
                    } else if(d==4) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p5a.setIcon(S6);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p5b.setIcon(S6);
                        }
                    } else if(d==5) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p6a.setIcon(S6);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p6b.setIcon(S6);
                        }
                    }
                } else if(players[d][c].contains ("S7")) {
                    if(d==0){
                        if(c==0) {
                            p1a.setIcon(S7);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p1b.setIcon(S7);
                        }
                    } else if(d==1) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p2a.setIcon(S7);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p2b.setIcon(S7);
                        }
                    } else if(d==2) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p3a.setIcon(S7);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p3b.setIcon(S7);
                        }
                    } else if(d==3) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p4a.setIcon(S7);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p4b.setIcon(S7);
                        }
                    } else if(d==4) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p5a.setIcon(S7);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p5b.setIcon(S7);
                        }
                    } else if(d==5) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p6a.setIcon(S7);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p6b.setIcon(S7);
                        }
                    }
                } else if(players[d][c].contains ("S8")) {
                    if(d==0){
                        if(c==0) {
                            p1a.setIcon(S8);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p1b.setIcon(S8);
                        }
                    } else if(d==1) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p2a.setIcon(S8);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p2b.setIcon(S8);
                        }
                    } else if(d==2) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p3a.setIcon(S8);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p3b.setIcon(S8);
                        }
                    } else if(d==3) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p4a.setIcon(S8);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p4b.setIcon(S8);
                        }
                    } else if(d==4) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p5a.setIcon(S8);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p5b.setIcon(S8);
                        }
                    } else if(d==5) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p6a.setIcon(S8);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p6b.setIcon(S8);
                        }
                    }
                } else if(players[d][c].contains ("S9")) {
                    if(d==0){
                        if(c==0) {
                            p1a.setIcon(S9);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p1b.setIcon(S9);
                        }
                    } else if(d==1) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p2a.setIcon(S9);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p2b.setIcon(S9);
                        }
                    } else if(d==2) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p3a.setIcon(S9);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p3b.setIcon(S9);
                        }
                    } else if(d==3) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p4a.setIcon(S9);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p4b.setIcon(S9);
                        }
                    } else if(d==4) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p5a.setIcon(S9);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p5b.setIcon(S9);
                        }
                    } else if(d==5) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p6a.setIcon(S9);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p6b.setIcon(S9);
                        }
                    }
                } else if(players[d][c].contains ("S10")) {
                    if(d==0){
                        if(c==0) {
                            p1a.setIcon(S10);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p1b.setIcon(S10);
                        }
                    } else if(d==1) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p2a.setIcon(S10);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p2b.setIcon(S10);
                        }
                    } else if(d==2) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p3a.setIcon(S10);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p3b.setIcon(S10);
                        }
                    } else if(d==3) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p4a.setIcon(S10);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p4b.setIcon(S10);
                        }
                    } else if(d==4) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p5a.setIcon(S10);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p5b.setIcon(S10);
                        }
                    } else if(d==5) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p6a.setIcon(S10);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p6b.setIcon(S10);
                        }
                    }
                } else if(players[d][c].contains ("SJ")) {
                    if(d==0){
                        if(c==0) {
                            p1a.setIcon(SJ);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p1b.setIcon(SJ);
                        }
                    } else if(d==1) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p2a.setIcon(SJ);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p2b.setIcon(SJ);
                        }
                    } else if(d==2) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p3a.setIcon(SJ);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p3b.setIcon(SJ);
                        }
                    } else if(d==3) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p4a.setIcon(SJ);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p4b.setIcon(SJ);
                        }
                    } else if(d==4) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p5a.setIcon(SJ);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p5b.setIcon(SJ);
                        }
                    } else if(d==5) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p6a.setIcon(SJ);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p6b.setIcon(SJ);
                        }
                    }
                } else if(players[d][c].contains ("SQ")) {
                    if(d==0){
                        if(c==0) {
                            p1a.setIcon(SQ);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p1b.setIcon(SQ);
                        }
                    } else if(d==1) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p2a.setIcon(SQ);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p2b.setIcon(SQ);
                        }
                    } else if(d==2) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p3a.setIcon(SQ);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p3b.setIcon(SQ);
                        }
                    } else if(d==3) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p4a.setIcon(SQ);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p4b.setIcon(SQ);
                        }
                    } else if(d==4) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p5a.setIcon(SQ);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p5b.setIcon(SQ);
                        }
                    } else if(d==5) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p6a.setIcon(SQ);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p6b.setIcon(SQ);
                        }
                    }
                } else if(players[d][c].contains ("SK")) {
                    if(d==0){
                        if(c==0) {
                            p1a.setIcon(SK);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p1b.setIcon(SK);
                        }
                    } else if(d==1) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p2a.setIcon(SK);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p2b.setIcon(SK);
                        }
                    } else if(d==2) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p3a.setIcon(SK);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p3b.setIcon(SK);
                        }
                    } else if(d==3) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p4a.setIcon(SK);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p4b.setIcon(SK);
                        }
                    } else if(d==4) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p5a.setIcon(SK);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p5b.setIcon(SK);
                        }
                    } else if(d==5) {
                        if(c==0) {
                            p6a.setIcon(SK);
                        } else if(c==1) {
                            p6b.setIcon(SK);
                        }
                    }
                }}}
```

This is only a part of it and I don't know how to shorten it.

Comment: That's not really long. That's really really really long long long.

Comment: use for the if d == 0...5 switch case. to make the stuff with p1a...p5a better put this in an array so you can iterate over it like pa[5]

Comment: Surely there is some way of looking up the 'pxx' component?  Are they not in a list somewhere?

Comment: Why dont you fill them up in structured Arraylist and set the Icons depenting on the arraylist?

Comment: When you have this amount of `if`s, you need to reconsider your design.. That's a sign.

Comment: What should the code do? If you can't express it in Java, at least tell us in English? I am not willing to read 2000 lines of code with non-descriptive variable names to infer the intended meaning ...

Comment: So I'm making this poker game and it just has to show which card every player has. I already have a code that randomly generates all the player cards and I just have set the Icons to the right cards here. I used 12 JLabels as cards (p1a~p6b) and players[d][c] contains the generated cards.

Answer (score 3):

I'd start by replacing the variable `p1a` through `p6b` with an array of "widgets" ... or whatever they are.  Then refactor to index the array to get the widget whose icon is to be set.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can see, your `players` is just an array of strings. What it should be is an array of

```
class Player {
   String name;
   Widget widget;
}
```

or similar, and you should have a

```
Map<String, Icon> icons
```

where you would do

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Icon> e : icons)
   if (players[d][c].name.contains(e.getKey()))
      players[d][c].widget.setIcon(e.getValue());
```

this would then replace the whole huge ifology cascade you have now.

Answer (score 1):

> So I'm making this poker game and it just has to show which card every player has. I already have a code that randomly generates all the player cards and I just have set the Icons to the right cards here. I used 12 JLabels as cards (p1a~p6b) and players[d][c] contains the generated cards.

First, let's choose a suitable data structure. For type safety, we'll want to have a dedicated type for a card. Since the set of values is small and known at compile time, an enum is good choice:

```
enum Card {
    SA, S2, S3, S4, S5, S6, S7, S8, S9, S10, SJ, SQ, SK;
}
```

Having that, we can represent the hands as arrays of Card:

```
Card[][] hand;
```

For display, we have

```
JLabel[][] labels;
```

We also need a place to keep the icon for each Card. That easiest if the Card itself knows its icon:

```
enum Card {
    SA, S2, S3, S4, S5, S6, S7, S8, S9, S10, SJ, SQ, SK;

    Icon icon = readIconFor(name());
}
```

We can then do:

```
void show(Card[][] hands) {
    for (int playerId = 0; playerId < 2; playerId++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            labels[playerId][i].setIcon(hand[playerId][i].icon);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A method you should implement that takes the name of the icon, and reads the icon from whereever you keep them.

Answer (score 0):

So you are calling setIcon() on an object, and passing in a parameter.  The rest of your code is just deciding which object, and which parameter.

If you make one decision about the parameter to pass, put it into a variable, and pass the variable, that dispenses with repetition just to get to a different variable.  Let's call that `currentIcon`.

We don't know enough about how the objects are organized.  Are they in (or could they be in) an array?  Instead of deciding what code to execute, can you decide which array element holds the object on which you want to call the method.  If they were all in, say, `playersArray`, you could decide which element, use `c` and `d` to index into that array, and end up with something like:

```
playersArray[c][d].setIcon(currentIcon);
```